# Getting Angular Service Workers Working on IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, service-worker, angular-service-worker

Is there a way how the [Angular Service Worker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro) can run with IE11? According to 
[CanIuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers), IE11 is not supported, but there seems to be a [Polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise#readme) for older browsers that provides Promises support, which as I understand, the Service Worker is built on top of it.

Anyone got the Angular Service Workers running on IE11 with that Polyfill?

Thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: Where did you get the notion that service workers are 'built on top of Promises'?

Comment: I meant they are making use of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is true that service workers make extensive use of Promises, this has nothing to do with the core functionality of service workers. IE11 has no implementation for Service Workers, and never will.